# UIPopover Error:'-[UIPopoverController init] is not a valid initializer. You must call -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:].'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to create a UIPopover, yet I can't. Here is the code I am using:
iAPAddOn.h:

```
#import "CodeaAddon.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InAppPurchasePopoverViewController.h"

id IAPAddOnInstance;

@interface IAPAddOn : UIPopoverController<CodeaAddon>
{
    UIPopoverController* popover;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) CodeaViewController *codeaViewController;

@end
```

iApAddOn.m:

```
#import "lua.h"
#import "IAPAddOn.h"

@implementation IAPAddOn

#pragma mark - Initialisation

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        IAPAddOnInstance = self;

        InAppPurchasePopoverViewController* popoverController = [[InAppPurchasePopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InAppPurchasePopover" bundle:nil];
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverController];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - CodeaAddon Delegate

- (void) codea:(CodeaViewController*)controller didCreateLuaState:(struct lua_State*)L
{
    NSLog(@"IAPAddOn Registering Functions");

    lua_register(L, "showIAPPopOver", showIAPPopOver);

    self.codeaViewController = controller;
}

#pragma mark - Init

static int showIAPPopOver(struct lua_State *state) {
    [IAPAddOnInstance showIAPPopOverAction];

    return 0;
}

- (void) showIAPPopOverAction {
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100) inView:self.codeaViewController.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:true];
}

@end
```

It results with a crash on startup and logging this in the console:

```
2014-02-02 01:44:37.131 StackIt[42088:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController init] is not a valid initializer. You must call -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:].'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x037725e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x031878b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x037723bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x00a86712 -[UIPopoverController init] + 59
    4   StackIt                             0x00006fae -[IAPAddOn init] + 78
    5   StackIt                             0x00002c19 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 617
    6   UIKit                               0x004b2355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    7   UIKit                               0x004b2b95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
    8   UIKit                               0x004b73a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    9   UIKit                               0x004cb87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    10  UIKit                               0x004cbde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    11  UIKit                               0x004b9025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x04d342f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x04d33e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x036edd65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x036eda9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0371877c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x03717ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x037178db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    19  UIKit                               0x004b6add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    20  UIKit                               0x004b8d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    21  StackIt                             0x0000297d main + 141
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x03ce770d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any help would be wonderful.
Thank you!

Comment: Why is this tagged "lua"? This is not Lua. This is Objective-C. Also, if "Xcode is not letting you", then change IDE. (Hint: it won't help. This has absolutely **nothing** to do with Xcode whatsoever. This has to do with you calling `self = [super init];` instead of `self = [super init];` and `[IAPAddon init]` which is - as you can tell from the exception message - not permitted.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Sorry, it was 1:30 AM, and I didn't quite know what to say. I tagged it as Lua, since this code is triggered by my Lua script, but it's not that related, I guess. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should have:

```
- (id)init
{
    InAppPurchasePopoverViewController* purchaseController = [[InAppPurchasePopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InAppPurchasePopover" bundle:nil];

    self = [super initWithContentViewController:purchaseController];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Because currently your class isn't respecting it's superclass requirements and is creating an additional popover controller which is not used properly. Everywhere you use `popover` should really be using `self`.